# Raspberry Pi Zero W auto login

Tags: linux, authentication, raspberry-pi, raspbian, debian-buster

I am trying to enable a headless auto login on a Raspberry Pi Zero W with Raspbian Booster 10.

I am interested in the Desktop interface, not the Command one, which works with auto login enabled.

I have tried the following:

1. sudo raspi config
2. modifying the lightdm conf for autologin-user and timeout

If necessary, i will provide the lightdm logs (cannot pastebin here, for whatever reason).

These have not worked. The login prompt always appears.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9rMtmgkm

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask your question if you don't get it answered here.